# Select the string which contains higher number

Tags: c#, string, list

I have a list of strings.

List items looks like :

```
CM_Manual_EN_rev.01   
CM_Manual_EN_rev.02   
CM_Manual_EN_REV.05   
CM_Manual_EN_REV.06   
CM_Manual_EN_REV.07   
...   
CM12-CM6K_Spare_parts_DK_rev.01    
CM12-CM6K_Spare_parts_DK_rev.03   
...
BT_Dansk_Manual_NOM
CM_Svensk_Manual
CM901-CM30_Manual_RUS
D_Polsk_Manual
HPB_spansk_old
```

If they have `rev.number` I would like to add to a listbox **just the one with the `highest rev.number`**,

**if they have no `rev.number`**, which means it's the only version, **then add it simply to a listbox.**

Thank you for helping !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit** (moved my old approach to the bottom)

Since you've asked me to help in your comments, here's a different approach which does what you want:

your sample data (first four lines are your newest requirement):

```
var list = new List<String>(){
    "CM901K_Spare_parts_EN_rev.04-2", 
    "CM901K_Spare_parts_EN_rev.04-1",
    "CM901K_Spare_parts_EN_rev.04-3",
    "CM901K_Spare_parts_EN_rev.04-2", 
    "rev.04-2",
    "CM_Manual_EN_rev.01", 
    "CM_Manual_EN_rev.02",  
    "CM_Manual_EN_REV.05",   
    "CM_Manual_EN_REV.06",   
    "CM_Manual_EN_REV.07",   
    "CM12-CM6K_Spare_parts_DK_rev.01",    
    "CM12-CM6K_Spare_parts_DK_rev.03",   
    "BT_Dansk_Manual_NOM",
    "CM_Svensk_Manual",
    "CM901-CM30_Manual_RUS",
    "D_Polsk_Manual",
    "HPB_spansk_old"
};
```

without revision first, then the other ordered by revision(highest per group):

```
var withRev = list.Where(s => s.IndexOf("rev.", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > -1);
var withoutRev = list.Except(withRev);

var orderedWithRev = withRev
    .Select(r => { 
        int RevIndex = r.LastIndexOf("rev.", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        String[] tokens = r
            .Substring(RevIndex + "rev.".Length)
            .Split(new[] { '-' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        return new
        {
            Item = r,
            RevIndex,
            RevisionItem = r.Substring(0, RevIndex),
            MainRevision = int.Parse(tokens[0]),
            SubRevision  = tokens.Length > 1 ? int.Parse(tokens[1]) : 0
        };
    })
    .GroupBy(x => x.RevisionItem.ToLower())
    .Select(g => g
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.MainRevision)
        .ThenByDescending( x => x.SubRevision)
        .First().Item);

foreach (var wr in withoutRev)
    listBox1.Items.Add(wr);
foreach (var r in orderedWithRev)
    listBox1.Items.Add(r);
```

Here's the demo: http://ideone.com/fGFZ7

---

old answer:

If the string has always above format, the easiest would be to use `Int32.Parse`, `String.Substring`, `String.LastIndexof` and `Enumerable.Max`:

```
int highestNum = list.Where(s => s.Contains("."))
                     .Max(s => int.Parse(s.Substring(s.LastIndexOf(".")+1)));
```

or to get the string:

```
String highestNumString = list.Where(s => s.Contains("."))
                     .OrderByDescending(s => int.Parse(s.Substring(s.LastIndexOf(".")+1)))
                     .First();
```

**Edit**: Here's a demo: http://ideone.com/0EeFg

Comment: Interesting approach, but I think the OP needs to have the text for the highest of each type of software returned, not the highest number.

Comment: exactly. I need the string which the highest rev. number. in this case "CM_Manual_EN_REV.07" . Thank you !

Comment: @Enigmativity: Edited my answer already after i've read the question again.

Comment: This is still only returning one string. It needs to return all the different software titles but only the latest version for each.

Comment: Not all string in the list has rev. number . How could I change this code to allow me an if statement ? in has rev. number order, if not just add it ? Thanks

Comment: @user1597284:  But you have accepted Enigmativity's answer by now, why are you asking me?

Comment: Wasn't working, because some of the strings does not contains rev. number. for example : "BT_Dansk_Manual_NOM". What I should do is to list the ones without rev. number and Add the ones of each string with highest rev. number. Do you know what I mean ? Thank you Tim !

Comment: I just made an edit and provided some other list item without rev. number. Please take a look, thanks for your time

Comment: @TimSchmelter Thank you Tim, works perfectly ! In future there will be strings in the list which looks like "CM901K_Spare_parts_EN_rev.04-1" . rev.04-1, or rev.04-2 . What will I have to modify in order to make them work ?

Comment: @user1597284: Edited my answer with your new requirement. Have a look at the new `OrderByDescending(MainRevision) + ThenByDescending(SubRevision)`.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
Func<string, Tuple<string, int>> split = t =>
{
    var a = t
        .ToLowerInvariant()
        .Split(new [] { "rev." }, StringSplitOptions.None);
    return Tuple.Create(a[0], a.Length == 2 ? int.Parse(a[1]) : 0);
};

var query =
    from i in items
    let s = split(i)
    group new { i, s.Item2 } by s.Item1 into g
    from m in g
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.Item2)
        .Take(1)
        .Select(x => x.i)
    select m;
```

I started with this input:

```
var items = new []
{
    "CM_Manual_EN_rev.01",
    "CM_Manual_EN_rev.02",
    "CM_Manual_EN_REV.05",
    "CM_Manual_EN_REV.06",
    "CM_Manual_EN_REV.07",
    "Foo", 
    "CM12-CM6K_Spare_parts_DK_rev.01",
    "CM12-CM6K_Spare_parts_DK_rev.03",
};
```

And got this output:

```
CM_Manual_EN_REV.07
Foo
CM12-CM6K_Spare_parts_DK_rev.03
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var result = list
              .Where(s => s.Contains('.'))
              .OrderByDescending(s => int.Parse(s.Substring(s.LastIndexOf('.') + 1)))
              .GroupBy(s => s.Substring(0, s.LastIndexOf('.') + 1).ToLower())
              .Select(s => s.First())
              .Union(list.Where(s => !s.Contains('.')));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use regular expressing to get number from string

```
string[] arr = { "CM_Manual_EN_rev.01", "CM_Manual_EN_rev.02", "CM_Manual_EN_rev.03" };
Regex re = new Regex(@"\d+");
foreach (string s in arr)
{
    Match m = re.Match(s);
    if (m.Success)
    {
        // use m.value to get highest no and compare then get index 
    }
}
```

i think now you can done rest code